I want to upload pdf document to slack app channel using slack api
As files.upload api is deprecated, so I am following below steps to upload file on slack app channel.

Call files.getUploadURLExternal, which returns an upload URL and a file ID.

Upload a file by making a POST request to the upload URL. Include the filename (e.g., -F filename="@text.txt"). Files are processed asynchronously via a job handler.
Files can be sent as raw bytes or can be multipart form encoded. Slack will return HTTP 200 if the upload is successful; a non-200 response indicates a failure.

Call files.completeUploadExternal to finalize the upload.
There is no need to wait for files to be processed by the job handler; the files.completeUploadExternal method will return with no action until both processes have completed. If files.completeUploadExternal is not called, the upload will be aborted and clients will recieve an error.


Now

first query: shall I add parameter as filename for second step as filename = "@sample.txt" ? I am using postman to call api, so i am using form-data to post file.

second issue: when sending pdf to slack api, PDF file sends successfully with thumbnail image but when i open pdf , it gets crashed. No pdf getting opened.


Screen shots of postman i am using for above steps.

calling files.getUploadURLExternal. First api call using postman


Calling URL which i got in first step. Second post api call to url which return from first step using postman


Calling third api: files.completeUploadExternal. third api call using postman and used fileid which return from first api

response from third api:


{
"ok": true,

"files": [

    {

        "id": "F07EN8MP0MN",

        "created": 1721886687,

        "timestamp": 1721886687,

        "name": "sample.pdf",

        "title": "Slack File Testing",

        "mimetype": "application/pdf",

        "filetype": "pdf",

        "pretty_type": "PDF",

        "user": "U--------------F",

        "user_team": "T-------------D",

        "editable": false,

        "size": 68000,

        "mode": "hosted",

        "is_external": false,

        "external_type": "",

        "is_public": false,

        "public_url_shared": false,

        "display_as_bot": false,

        "username": "",

        "url_private": "https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T----------D-F07EN8MP0MN/sample.pdf",

        "url_private_download": "https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T----------D-F07EN8MP0MN/download/sample.pdf",

        "media_display_type": "unknown",

        "thumb_pdf": "https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/T---A---F07EN8MP0MN-b6f9307532/sample_thumb_pdf.png",

        "thumb_pdf_w": 935,

        "thumb_pdf_h": 1210,

        "permalink": "https://arm.slack.com/files/U-----PF/F07EN8MP0MN/sample.pdf",

        "permalink_public": "https://slack-files.com/T-----D-F07-------0MN-1617----9d",

        "comments_count": 0,

        "is_starred": false,

        "shares": {

            "private": {

                "D07CF63GJCQ": [

                    {

                        "reply_users": [],

                        "reply_users_count": 0,

                        "reply_count": 0,

                        "ts": "1721886752.605329",

                        "share_user_id": "U0-------PF",

                        "source": "UNKNOWN"

                    }

                ]

            }

        },

        "channels": [],

        "groups": [],

        "ims": [

            "D0-------GJC-"

        ],

        "has_more_shares": false,

        "has_rich_preview": false,

        "file_access": "visible"

    }

]

}
got pdf in slack:
PDF sent successfully to slack app channel

Error when opening pdf:

What am I doing wrong?
Ref: sample.pdf link https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T021GH7B6AD-F07EN8MP0MN/sample.pdf

facing same issue. happened to find any fix or workaround?
